# Excon::Error::RequestEntityTooLarge: Expected(200) <=> Actual(413 Request Entity Too Large) : Fog google storage ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-storage, fog

I have a rails app 5.2, ruby 2.3.4 with fog-google (1.3.3).

It was working great on dev, test and prod environnement since a long time to upload and download file.

But now fog storage refuse to upload file.

If i'm oppening a rails c and put

```
config = Rails.application.config.x.settings["cloud_storage"]

fogStorage = Fog::Storage.new(
 provider: "Google",
 google_storage_access_key_id:     config["access_key_id"],
 google_storage_secret_access_key: config["secret_access_key"]
)

storageBucket = fogStorage.directories.new key: config["bucket"]

file_name = File.join(Rails.root,"DSC00174.jpg")
file = File.open(file_name, "r")
image = storageBucket.files.new(
  key: "logo_client_image_test/AAA.jpg",
  body: file.read,
  public: true
  content_type:'image/jpeg'
)
image.save
puts image.public_url
```

I got this message

```
Excon::Error::RequestEntityTooLarge: Expected(200) <=> Actual(413 Request Entity Too Large)
excon.error.response
  :body          => "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\">\n  <title>Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>413.</b> <ins>That\xE2\x80\x99s an error.</ins>\n  <p>Your client issued a request that was too large.\n <script>\n  (function() { var c=function(a,d,b){a=a+\"=deleted\"+(\"; path=\"+d);null!=b&&(a+=\"; domain=\"+b);document.cookie=a+\"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT\"};var g=function(a){var d=e,b=location.hostname;c(d,a,null);c(d,a,b);for(var f=0;;){f=b.indexOf(\".\",f+1);if(0>f)break;c(d,a,b.substring(f+1))}};var h;if(4E3<unescape(encodeURI(document.cookie)).length){for(var k=document.cookie.split(\";\"),l=[],m=0;m<k.length;m++){var n=k[m].match(/^\\s*([^=]+)/);n&&l.push(n[1])}for(var p=0;p<l.length;p++){var e=l[p];g(\"/\");for(var q=location.pathname,r=0;;){r=q.indexOf(\"/\",r+1);if(0>r)break;var t=q.substring(0,r);g(t);g(t+\"/\")}\"/\"!=q.charAt(q.length-1)&&(g(q),g(q+\"/\"))}h=!0}else h=!1;\nh&&setTimeout(function(){if(history.replaceState){var a=location.href;history.replaceState(null,\"\",\"/\");location.replace(a)}},1E3); })();\n\n</script>\n <ins>That\xE2\x80\x99s all we know.</ins>\n"
  :cookies       => [
  ]
  :headers       => {
    "Content-Length"  => "2398"
    "Content-Type"    => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    "Date"            => "Thu, 19 Jul 2018 10:11:50 GMT"
    "Referrer-Policy" => "no-referrer"
  }
  :host          => "locabri.storage.googleapis.com"
  :local_address => "192.168.1.44"
  :local_port    => 51136
  :path          => "/logo_client_image_test%2FAAADSC00174.jpg"
  :port          => 443
  :reason_phrase => "Request Entity Too Large"
  :remote_ip     => "216.58.206.240"
  :status        => 413
  :status_line   => "HTTP/1.0 413 Request Entity Too Large\r\n"
```

The file size is 98ko.
I can transfert the file manually to the google bucket with the online interface.

The only change I've done recently is to upgrade Rails to 5.2. and config file haven't change.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. In rails 5.2 body has to be file not file.read

```
image = storageBucket.files.new(
key: "logo_client_image_test/AAA.jpg",
body: file,
public: true
content_type:'image/jpeg'
)
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>